# Could not extract result set after using page(pagable) springboot

Tags: spring-boot, pagination

**Repository**

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM Invoiceupload.invoiceupload where email=:email", nativeQuery=true)

public Page getInvoiceDetailByEmail(String email,Pageable pageable);
```

**Controller**

```
// View all invoices by a vendor

    @GetMapping("/viewByEmail/{email}")
    public Page<Map<String,Object>> getVendorInvoices(@RequestHeader (value="Authorization") String token,@PathVariable("email") String email,Pageable pageable){

        if(request.checkVendorTokenValidity(token)!= null) {    

            return invoiceRepository.getInvoiceDetailByEmail(email, pageable);
        }
        else
            throw new Unauthorized(ErrorMessages.NOT_AUTHORISED);
    }
```

I am trying to fetch all invoices from db passing email,for now I have 19 invoice records in my db 
So when i try to run this endpoint from post man it works fine ,returns all 19 invoices
BUT when I added another invoice (total=20) it failed to fetch

**error:**

> could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

When I tried  replacing  Page> with List> it worked fine,
**so i think there is a problem in page  and pageable ,can some one please help**

Comment: refer to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query#2-native-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable pagination for native queries , you needs to declare an additional attribute in your native query. That is `countQuery`.

```
 @Query(value="SELECT * FROM Invoiceupload where email=:email", 
  countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM Invoiceupload", 
  nativeQuery = true)
Page<Invoiceupload> getInvoiceDetailByEmail(@Param("email")String email,Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work. Still facing the same issue

Comment: Did you build Pageable properly ?Use PageRequest.of(....) method

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Comment: @ChaitanyaBijawe I hope the above solution worked. That's why the solution has been accepted. Are you facing any issue?

Comment: I finally ended up by refering this https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008BEfEo/has-anybody-built-an-application-using-java-spring-framework-that-connects-to-snowflake

My problem was the query generating for pagination was having

limit 5,10 [5 is the limit and 10 is the offset.]
in snowflake we have to pass "offset" explicitly like limit 5 offset 10. By creating empty dialect the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. I tried to fetch persian data from italic collact column. I changed collact database to utf8-persian_ci and fixed